# mysqldump Fully Qualifies Triggers with Database Name

Tags: database, mysql, database-backups

I'm am trying to use mysqldump to export a database which needs to be imported using a different database name. Looking at the SQL generated by mysqldump, it appears that triggers are the only object names which are fully-qualified with the source database name thus foiling my needs. Is there anyway to direct mysqldump to not fully-qualify any object names including triggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the solution. I was using MySQL Workbench to design my database and I've created some triggers there. All of them used the syntax `CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name` except for one: `CREATE TRIGGER dbname.trigger_name` (it was just my mistake). Mysqldump output included all triggers in the same way: only one had database name.

Mysqldump uses your original `CREATE TRIGGER` instructions which you can see via `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER`. If you have a trigger defined with a database name, simply replace it (drop and create) with a one without dbname.

Comment: I won't be verifying this (it's been over two years since I've needed it, and I won't be needing it in the foreseeable future), but this sounds like a plausible and practical solution, so I'm marking it as the answer! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Ha, I see @emre actually suggested this solution over a year ago and I shot him down. None-the-less, his was a suspicion and yours is an insistence, so I'll leave you with the marked answer. Certainly if any finds evidence to the contrary, we'll consider that then. For now, I think there is a good chance your advise will help others.

Comment: well, I just tested it, because I had the same problem. If it's important, my MySQL server version is 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you add the database name when you create the trigger. Try updating your trigger without the database name in it.

Comment: it's been a while since I've had to deal with this, but I'm pretty sure that the issue was not due to creating the triggers using the fully qualified database name: mysqldump would generate the trigger creation script with database name fully qualified regardless of how I created them.

Answer (score -1):

Not an ideal solution but pumping the output through the following has gotten rid of the database name on the triggers for me.

```
mysqldump ... opts ... | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/'
```